# What do you do when padding/margin gets in the way of content on small screens?

Tags: css, responsive-design, frontend

I understand that other questions have touched on this topic in various forms, but none as directly as I would like in a definitive answer.

When building a view, padding and margin are useful in all the ways you expect. As you read this page, imagine how much more difficult it would be to navigate if all the spacing from the surrounding elements was collapsed so that everything was squeezed together.

When I am designing a view, I will often add `10px` padding to a text box, or space apart buttons with a `5px` margin. But on small resolution displays and (equivalently) on those with small [device pixel ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) settings (often phones and laptops where the CSS pixels are scaled to make the webpage usable, or where browser users press `ctrl +`), that padding/margin takes up valuable real-estate in the pursuit of making the webpage small device friendly.

If screen resolution is limited, or the device pixel ratio is scaled strongly, a `10px` padding is going to take up a different percentage of the screen than it would on a desktop. What is intended to be a small logical separation turns into a large wall. So how do I keep paddings/borders small?

It would be nice if it was possible to make padding/margin responsive so that didn't take up too much of the screen. But units in CSS don't correspond to their physics lengths, percentages produce different values based on the reference element, media queries would be burdensome, and the viewport CSS units also have limitations.

Answer (score 0):

They're is a bunch of other units you could use beside px:

1. `em`: Relative to the font-size of the element (Used quite often in modern web design)
2. `ex`:   Relative to the x-height of the current font
3. `ch`:   Relative to the width of the "0"
4. `rem`: Relative to font-size of the root element (Quite common too ...)
5. `vw`: Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport
6. `vh`: Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport (Same here)
7. `%:` Relative to the parent element

And much more... I think if I remember, Bootstrap for exemple is based on em's.
So coming back to your problem, you could have a dynamic font size with a dynamic padding and margins system based on `em`. Hope this help. gl.